# Group the people of same location of 1 km² area

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to group the people of same location of 1 km² area. I am getting the langitude and longitude of people and I want to group them according to it in a number for identification of the group of people sharing same location of 1 km² area.

I am new to node.js.

Thanks all

Comment: I think the question is severely underconstrained to be answered. If you have a set of points, there are multiple ways to group them in areas. In fact those groups could have multiple shapes and satisfy the 1km2 area constrain. If those shapes are defined in some way, you could test each person for which area it belongs, and have a Map of Sets (or even an array).

But, as stated, the question is too open. You should add info and specify what have you tried and what the problem is with that approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best approach would be to use a standardized grid system, there are many around, for example [MGRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Grid_Reference_System) is the one NATO uses and can give us varying levels of accuracy.

We can use a module such as [mgrs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mgrs) to get us the grid reference for a user's lat/long, then we can group these users using, for example, lodash's [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy). One could also use Array.reduce for this purpose, but _.groupBy is very handy for this type of problem.

```
const mgrs = require("mgrs");
const _ = require("lodash");

// Some sample users living within a few kms 
let users = [
    { first: 'Andreias', last: 'Aragão', lat: 51.51697, lon: -0.11894 },
    { first: 'Babür', last: 'Erberk', lat: 51.50041, lon: -0.12823 },
    { first: 'William', last: 'Jørgensen', lat: 51.49879, lon: -0.13041 },
    { first: 'Clyde', last: 'Crawford', lat: 51.50928, lon: -0.1226 },
    { first: 'Silvijn', last: 'Werts', lat: 51.49843, lon: -0.12066 },
    { first: 'Jokubas', last: 'Laastad', lat: 51.50517, lon: -0.12312 },
    { first: 'Rebecca', last: 'Lawson', lat: 51.5018, lon: -0.12786 },
    { first: 'Oscar', last: 'Opland', lat: 51.50123, lon: -0.13245 },
    { first: 'Cláudio', last: 'Costa', lat: 51.50354, lon: -0.13123 },
    { first: 'Juan', last: 'Ruiz', lat: 51.50796, lon: -0.12884 }
]

// Add user MGRS grid square
users = users.map(user => {
    // Get MGRS grid location accurate to ~1km
    user.mgrs = mgrs.forward([user.lon, user.lat], 2);
    return user;
})

const usersByLocation = _.groupBy(users, "mgrs");
console.log(usersByLocation);
```

This will give us an output that looks like so:

```
{
    '30UXC9911': [
        {
          first: 'Andreias',
          last: 'Aragão',
          lat: 51.51697,
          lon: -0.11894,
          mgrs: '30UXC9911'
        }
      ],
      '30UXC9909': [
        {
          first: 'Babür',
          last: 'Erberk',
          lat: 51.50041,
          lon: -0.12823,
          mgrs: '30UXC9909'
        },
        {
          first: 'William',
          last: 'Jørgensen',
          lat: 51.49879,
          lon: -0.13041,
          mgrs: '30UXC9909'
        },
        {
          first: 'Silvijn',
          last: 'Werts',
          lat: 51.49843,
          lon: -0.12066,
          mgrs: '30UXC9909'
        },
        {
          first: 'Jokubas',
          last: 'Laastad',
          lat: 51.50517,
          lon: -0.12312,
          mgrs: '30UXC9909'
        },
        {
          first: 'Rebecca',
          last: 'Lawson',
          lat: 51.5018,
          lon: -0.12786,
          mgrs: '30UXC9909'
        },
        {
          first: 'Oscar',
          last: 'Opland',
          lat: 51.50123,
          lon: -0.13245,
          mgrs: '30UXC9909'
        },
        {
          first: 'Cláudio',
          last: 'Costa',
          lat: 51.50354,
          lon: -0.13123,
          mgrs: '30UXC9909'
        }
      ],
      '30UXC9910': [
        {
          first: 'Clyde',
          last: 'Crawford',
          lat: 51.50928,
          lon: -0.1226,
          mgrs: '30UXC9910'
        },
        {
          first: 'Juan',
          last: 'Ruiz',
          lat: 51.50796,
          lon: -0.12884,
          mgrs: '30UXC9910'
        }
      ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped

Comment: Glad to be of help!